# Combining global redux store with local state of the component

Tags: reactjs, redux

The challenge I came across is using global store slice, namely 'genres', which is an array of objects, in a local state to manipulate check/uncheck of the checkboxes. The problem occurs when I'm trying to use props.genres in the initial state. Looks like I'm getting an empty array from props.genres when the local state is initialized.

```
const Filters = (props) => {
    const { genres, getSelected, loadGenres, getGenres, clearFilters } = props
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(() =>
        genres.map(genre => (
            {id: genre.id, value: genre.name, checked: false}
        ))
    )
    const optionsSortBy = [
        {name: 'Popularity descending', value: 'popularity.desc'},
        {name: 'Popularity ascending', value: 'popularity.asc'},
        {name: 'Rating descending', value: 'vote_average.desc'},
        {name: 'Rating ascending', value: 'vote_average.asc'},
    ]
    const d = new Date()
    let currentYear = d.getFullYear()
    let optionsReleaseDate = R.range(1990, currentYear + 1).map(year => (
        {name: year + '', value: year}
    ))

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `${C.API_ENDPOINT}genre/movie/list`
        loadGenres(url, C.OPTIONS)
    }, [])

    const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
        let target = e.target
        getGenres(target)
    }

    const handleSelect = (e) => {
        let target = e.target
        let action = isNaN(target.value) ? 'SORT_BY' : 'RELEASE_DATE'
        getSelected(action, target)
    }

    const handleSubmitBtn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        clearFilters()
    }

    return (
        <form className={classes.FiltersBox}>
            <Submit submited={handleSubmitBtn} />
            <Select name="Sort By:" options={optionsSortBy} changed={handleSelect} />
            <Select name="Release date:" options={optionsReleaseDate} changed={handleSelect} />
            <Genres genres={isChecked} changed={handleCheckbox} />
        </form>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        genres: state.fetch.genres,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadGenres: (url, options) => dispatch(A.getApiData(url, options)),
        getGenres: (targetItem) => dispatch({
            type: 'CHECK_GENRES',
            payload: targetItem
        }),
        getSelected: (actionType, targetItem) => dispatch({
            type: actionType,
            payload: targetItem,
        }),
        clearFilters: () => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_FILTERS'})
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filters);
```

```
import * as R from 'ramda';
import fetchJSON from '../utils/api.js';

export const getApiData = (url, options) => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetchJSON(url, options)
    const data = response.body
    const dataHas = R.has(R.__, data)
    let actionType = dataHas('genres') ? 'FETCH_GENRES' : 'FETCH_MOVIES'

    dispatch({
        type: actionType,
        payload: data
    })
}
```

```
export const fetchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { payload } = action
    if (action.type === 'FETCH_GENRES') {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            genres: [...payload.genres]
        }
    }
    if (action.type === 'FETCH_MOVIES') {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            movies: [...payload.results]
        }
    }
    return state
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the reducer as well? I am assuming you might have issue in naming of the reducer. In addition, have you checked that your load `loadGenres` will run on every update. It means every time a component updates there is a call to the API.

Comment: Try to initialize your local state with an empty array `const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);` and then map it inside `useEffect`

Comment: `setIsChecked(genres.map(genre => ({id: genre.id, value: genre.name, checked: false})))` in useEffect

Comment: Added the reducer to the question

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do of setting initial value for state from props, is possible but isn't react best practice.  Consider initial your data as empty array and through `useEffect` manipulate state

---

```
 // didn't understand if its array or bool
 const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([])
 useEffect(()=>genres&& {  setIsChecked(... perform action...)
                                 }   ,[genres])
```

Comment: I want the list of genres to be fetched only once in the useEffect. Take it from props and use that data localy

Comment: Because `geners` isn't supposed to change the effect manipulate data only once

Answer (score 0):

You approach is almost correct.
I am not sure how the state should look like, when you have fetched your data.
I can see in the `mapStateToProps` is trying to access a value which is not defined at the beginning. If `state.fetch` is `undefined` you can not access `genres`.

Attempt 1:
You can solve it by using lodash.get https://lodash.com/docs/#get
It will catch up for the `undefined` problem.

Attempt 2: 
You can defined an initial state where your values are defined with mock data.

`const initialState = {fetch: {genres: []}}`

and use it your reducer

Comment: That is how the initialState looks like:

Comment: `const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    movies: [],
    genres: [],
    genresChecked: {},
    filters: {
        page: 1,
        sort_by: 'popularity.desc',
        primary_release_year: null,
        with_genres: ''
    }
}`